# Getting array in an angular custom directive from parent scope results an empty array with a strange behavior

Tags: angularjs

Still new in Angular world and I have a `categoriesController` wrapping a custom directive `categories-select` like this:

```
<div ng-controller="categoriesController" ng-init="init()">
    <categories-select></categories-select>
</div>


angular.module('app')
    .directive('categoriesSelect', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'categoriesSelectTemplate',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            console.log($scope)
            console.log($scope.categories)
        }],
    }
}])
```

The `categoriesController` has an **array of categories**.

The strange behavior I get inside the directive is:

[image]

So, whenever I try to get the categories array to do something with it, I find that it's empty, but it's -at the same time- populated in the `$scope`!

I tried also to isolate the directive scope and pass the array object to it, but I got the same strange behavior, but anyway, I want to know why this simple code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always pass necessary parameters inside directive, never share parent scope.
So looking on each directive you see what is required, never got unknown behaviour.

so Angular directive:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('categoriesSelect', [function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
       categories: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'categoriesSelectTemplate',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        console.log($scope)
        console.log($scope.categories)
    }],
}
}])
```

and HTML:

```
<categories-select categories="categories"></categories-select>
```

Edited:

I think your directive controller is getting initialised before categories coming from parent scope. try to draw categories on directive HTML and you will get them, or use $scope.$watchCollection inside directive controller

```
$scope.$watchCollection('categories', function (newVal, oldVal) {      
     console.log(newVal); 
});
```

Comment: Oh, you saved me! your "Edit" was right, but still don't understand why the first console.log shows the array as populated?

Comment: this is browser console magic! by the time browser prints $scope, categories already there, but printing direct field like $scope.categories browser understand it is still empty... don't know. looks like consoling $scope is bad approach is you got some missunderstanding